# Google Chrome 21 does not replying to websockets connections

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I cannot open any web socket applications on Google chrome version 21(latest). Applications runs smoothly in firefox. what can be possible reasons.

Comment: Which websocket server are you using?  If you've written your own, please post its handshaking code.  It'd also be useful to see your client code.

Comment: @simonc is right... if you can put your client code on jsfiddle and/or jsbin it will help see what is going on.

Comment: Does the echo test on websocket.org work for you? http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the problem. The firewall was blocking the web socket connections.